# How do I align vertical text in a flex box element

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I've been trying to create vertical text section title for each section on my website but I've been having a hard time trying to align them with other components. I have the title and the content as two elements in a flex box. I want to place the title at the top right corner of its flex element but I have no idea on how to actually do it.

I heard that the `origin-DIRECTION` css class can help with this but when I tried it, all it does is throw the text around the flex box and sometimes it clips through other components.

[Image of the problem; made background green for visibility.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9C3nk.png)

Here is the code in my App component.

```
<div className="flex my-[35vh]">
    <SectionCard name={"Projects"} />
    <Projects />
</div>
```

Here is the code for my SectionCard component.

```
export const SectionCard: React.FC<{ name: string }> = ({ name }) => {
    return (
        <div className="flex font-metropolis font-bold text-3xl items-center gap-8 -rotate-90">
            <div className="bg-black h-2 w-[10rem]"></div>
            <p>
                {name}  
            </p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**1. Using flex box**

> You should use `justify-content: end` and remove the item-center class

```
export const SectionCard: React.FC<{ name: string }> = ({ name }) => {
return (
    <div className="flex font-metropolis font-bold text-3xl gap-8 -rotate-90">
        <div className="bg-black h-2 w-[10rem]" style={{"justify-content":"end" ></div>
        <p>
            {name}  
        </p>
    </div>
);
```

}

**2. Using position rule**

Just remove the inner flex and some position css rules like absolute and relative to achieve this.

I just removed the classes `flex items-center gap-8`

```
export const SectionCard: React.FC<{ name: string }> = ({ name }) => {
return (
    <div className="font-metropolis font-bold text-3xl -rotate-90" style={{"position":"relative"}}>
        <div className="bg-black h-2 w-[10rem]" style={{"position":"absolute","top":"0","right":"0","padding":"10px"></div>
        <p>
            {name}  
        </p>
    </div>
   );
}
```

Comment: Neither of these actually place the text in the right spot. [Images of what it looks like with these changes](https://imgur.com/a/HayDww5). The text is actually outside of the flex box in both; both elements clip each other in the second.

Comment: If you can, share the html and css

Comment: I've moved the code that is necessary for this into this [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/Fr50Q358).

Comment: Try to add code in stackblitz because pastebin does not includes the css and necessary modules. Using that we  can npm install the css module required for this

Comment: For some reason the tailwind css installation does not persist across refreshes so you will have to run the commands from step 2 [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/vite) for the css to work. [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-s3hnyz?file=src%2FApp.tsx).